# Why is this line integral not $0$? (An incorrect application?)

Tags: real-analysis

I think I am little off my game tonight, but can someone tell me why this integral is not $0$?

$$\int_{C} x^2 - y^2 ds$$

where $C$ is an ellipse and $ds = \sqrt{ (dx/dt)^2 + (dy/dt)^2} dt$

To save you from doing any calculation, check the result [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B%2825Cos%5E2%5Bt%5D%20-%2049Sin%5E2%5Bt%5D%20%29*Sqrt%5B25Sin%5E2%5Bt%5D%20%2B%2049Cos%5E2%5Bt%5D%5D%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C2*Pi%7D%5D).

I thought that the integral has to be zero because $f(x,y) = x^2 - y^2$ is analytic on $\Bbb R^2$, which is simply-connected and the ellipse is certainly a closed loop, in fact it is a convex curve. This, I thought, should also mean that $f$ is conservative (I haven't done the  other calculations to verify because I am halted by the current problem and don't want to waste my time doing the calculation)

I feel like I overlooked something.

Comment: $f(x,y)$ is conservative if $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$. Here the partials with respect to $x$ and $y$, respectively, are $2x$ and $-2y$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you were trying to use the fact that if $F$ is a conservative vector field on $\Bbb R^2$, then $\int_C \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r} = 0$ for every closed loop $C$ in $\Bbb R^2$. However, your $f$ is not gradient, so you cannot apply result in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If $x(t) = a~cos(t)$ and $y(t) = b~sin(t)$, then taking derivatives and substituting yields

$\int_0^{2 \pi } \left(x(t)^2-y(t)^2\right)
   \sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial x(t)}{\partial t}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial x(t)}{\partial t}\right)^2} \, dt = \\
\int_0^{2 \pi} \sqrt{a^2 \sin ^2(t)+b^2 \sin ^2(t)} \left(a^2 \cos ^2(t)-b^2 \sin
   ^2(t)\right) \, dt = \\
\frac{4}{3} \left(a^2-2 b^2\right) \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \ne 0$ (in general).